# Why am I getting a KeyError: "0" for the following code?

Tags: python

I am running the following for loop and after the first iteration, I receive an error.

```
for index, obj in enumerate(client.list_objects("preprocess", recursive=True), start=1):
    j = get_json("preprocess", f"batch_{index}.json")
    x = client.get_object(
        "preprocess",
        f"batch_{index}.json",
    )
    data = json.load(x)
    calc(data)
```

The following is the calc function.

```
def calc(
    df,
):

    lat_pool = data["pickup_longitude"]
    lon_pool = data["pickup_latitude"]
    for key in range(
        len(lat_pool)
    ):
        lat = lat_pool[str(key)]
        lon = lon_pool[str(key)]
        if (lat > zero_point_lat) and (lon > zero_point_long):
            print("Area 1")
        elif (lat < zero_point_lat) and (lon < zero_point_long):
            print("Area 2")
        elif (lat < zero_point_lat) and (lon > zero_point_long):
            print("Area 3")
        elif (lat > zero_point_lat) and (lon < zero_point_long):
            print("Area 4")
```

**After the first iteration** that is successful, **I receive the following error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andreas/Desktop/mapper/mapper/handler.py", line 101, in <module>
    calc(data)
  File "/home/andreas/Desktop/mapper/mapper/handler.py", line 78, in calc
    lat = lat_pool[str(key)]
KeyError: '0'
```

I suppose it has something to do with `lat = lat_pool[str(key)]` but I can't solve it.

Comment: The error message directly tells you what is wrong: doing `str(key)` results in the string `'0'`, and there is no such key in `lat_pool`. In your own words: what keys do you expect `lat_pool` to have, and why? What **type** do you expect `lat_pool` to have, and why? Now, did you *check* those expectations? Are they correct? If not, do you understand why? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: It's not really possible to tell you more than that, because we can't see your `data`. As an aside: note that as written, `calc` will **ignore** the passed-in `df` value and look for a **global** `data` variable. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to iterate over the keys of `lat_pool` you need to do so explicitly by calling `lat_pool.keys()`

There could be other reasons for the error as well depending on how your data is and additional information would be needed to solve those

Hence the code would be -

```
def calc(
    df,
):

    lat_pool = data["pickup_longitude"]
    lon_pool = data["pickup_latitude"]
    for key in lat_pool.keys():
        lat = lat_pool[str(key)]
        lon = lon_pool[str(key)]
        if (lat > zero_point_lat) and (lon > zero_point_long):
            print("Area 1")
        elif (lat < zero_point_lat) and (lon < zero_point_long):
            print("Area 2")
        elif (lat < zero_point_lat) and (lon > zero_point_long):
            print("Area 3")
        elif (lat > zero_point_lat) and (lon < zero_point_long):
            print("Area 4")
```